# Dynamics 365 - PreImage & PostImage have the same values

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a plugin registered on an entity Update on post Operation synchronously and I have two images registered:

- PreImage with 3 fields
- PostImage with the same 3 fields

When it triggers, the new values are present in the PreImage as well.

```
Entity PreImageEntity = (Entity)crmContext.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];
Entity PostImageEntity = (Entity)crmContext.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
```

I need to have the old and the new value.

Some others plugin are plugged to the same entity on PostOperation and for the same event but the context should be the same for all the plugins...

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Can you consolidate all your plugins, steps, execution order of them? Then disable all & enable one by one to test the behavior.

Comment: You can be pretty confident that this is not a bug with the plugin execution pipeline. I would double check the registration of the PreImage and your usage of the images within the plugin.

Comment: Is the same plugin step perhaps registered multiple times?

Comment: Could you provide us with some screenshots of how you have registered the all the plugins. I suspect the issue has to do with multiple plugins firing on the same message. Also the context would not necessarily be the same for all plugins. Execution order and what happens in the plugin logic matters.

Comment: Sorry the project is quite huge and spotted that a workflow was activated by mistake. Workflows are getting executed before plugins...

Comment: @HubertSolecki so this is solved?